# Video controls in Chrome shake when I'm watching YouTube videos in Flash

Tags: macos, google-chrome

So when I'm watching embedded videos from YouTube on websites in Mac OSX Lion in Google Chrome browser, the video controller bar shakes and looks weird if I mouse off the video to make the controls disappear. Is there a fix for this weirdness?

Comment: How about on safari or fox?

Answer (score 1):

Update Google Chrome to the latest version and try disabling the [experimental HTML5 player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) for YouTube.